# Assigning Different Class to the first appended div in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am building a Bootstrap carousel div stack using d3.  I need the first div to have class = item active and all of the rest to be just item.  Code below:

```
var slides = d3.select(".carousel-inner").selectAll("div")
            .data(data).enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","active")
            .attr("id",function(d) {return d.waferId;})
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","container-fluid")
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","row");
```

I've played with using 'classed'

```
d3.select(".active").classed('item',true);
```

but doesn't seem to work.  I'm sure there is an easy answer but I'm new to d3.  Any advice is always appreciated.

The following did not work either:

```
    var slides = d3.select(".carousel-inner").selectAll("div")
            .data(data).enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","active")
            .attr("id",function(d) {return d.waferId;})
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","container-fluid")
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","row");

        d3.selectAll(".active").classed('item', function(d, i) { return i == 0; });
```

Comment: From what you say the code should be the other way round, i.e. assign class "item" to everything and then run `d3.selectAll(".item").classed('active', function(d, i) { return i == 0; });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3's `classed()` can take a function, just like the `attr()` and `style()` functions:

```
d3.selectAll(".active").classed('item', function(d, i) { return i == 0 });
```

NOTE: Uses `selectAll(".active")` rather than `select(".active")` like you had it.

Comment: Thanks for the response meetamit.  I tried the following:

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with your recommendation.  I ran and it did not correct the problem.

Comment: @chemnteach Based on what you're showing, it should work. Notice Lars's comment; maybe that's what's happening. Also, check in the console whether the class is actually being assigned or not. console.log `d` and `i`. Or create a working jsFiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I had a jquery error that I wasn't seeing that was preventing your solution for happening.  That is corrected and it is now set up correctly.  And Lars correction was of assistance as well.  Thanks to you both.